# Modem doesn't connect to internet (H9601 prolink)

Tags: internet-connection, usb-modem, 9.04, pppoe

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 and I have a Conextant H9601 PROLINK modem.. I installed it using eciadsl and I made a synch.bin using XP too but when I give the command eciadsl-start this is what happens.

```
[EciAdsl 1/5] Setting up USB support...

Preliminary USB device filesystem is OK
Loading UHCI support... Warning: uhci-hcd module doesn't exist

[EciAdsl 2/5] Uploading firmware...

firmware loaded successfully

[EciAdsl 3/5] Synchronization...


 Please Wait.. Synchronisation in progress [-]
 Please Wait.. Synchronisation in progress [\]
 Please Wait.. Synchronisation in progress [|]
 Please Wait.. Synchronisation in progress [/]
 Please Wait.. Synchronisation i
OK eciadsl-synch: success                                                           
Synchronization successful

[EciAdsl 4/5] Connecting to provider...

Connection successful

[EciAdsl 5/5] Setting up route table...

Waiting for tap0... 
ERROR: couldn't set your static IP or your external gateway
If you don't use PPPoE, please check your configuration.

Eventhough it says the connection is successful. I can't connect to internet
pls help... I'm new to ubuntu..



After Madukas suggestion and I tried it and typed eciadsl-start after rebooting. The same thing came up then I tried for another 2 or 3 times then it said.

ERROR: eciadsl-pppoeci is already running!
You should kill all instances of eciadsl-pppoeci and restart this script.

then I typed ifconfig then,

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:68:7b:e1:89  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:252 Base address:0xc000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:240 (240.0 B)  TX bytes:240 (240.0 B)

tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:2d:83:26:55:b1  
          inet6 addr: fe80::102d:83ff:fe26:55b1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)
```

I tried to use Firefox but nothing came up.

Answer (score 0):

Open up a terminal from Applications -> Accessories. Type:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modules
```

At the bottom of the file, make two new lines, like this:

```
usbserial
option
```

Then close the editor program and save it. Reboot the computer and hopefully you’ll be right from now on!